# What is Inquiry function in OpenGl

Tags: c++, opengl

What is Inquiry function in OpenGl?
I need to know a function to determine display device parameters, but i dont know what is function in OpenGl name?

Comment: Determine display device parameters? Do you mean things like refresh rate, screen size, etc? That is outside the scope of OpenGL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on which parameters you need, but [`glGet`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/docbook4/xhtml/glGet.xml) is a good start.